# display result in gridview

Tags: asp.net

HI all
I have a gridview containing columns as written below.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="QUARTERNAME" HeaderText="Quarter" 
       SortExpression="QUARTERNAME" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="60%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" 
               ImageUrl="~/btnimages/upload-btn.jpg" CommandName="UploadVATReport"
               OnClick="BtnSubmit_click" 
               CommandArgument='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("PK_VATPAYMENTID")) %>' />

            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"  Text="Online Status" />     
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

In this, what i want to do is, when i click the imagebutton called submitbutton, i want to show the result in the label of the corresponding row.Pls help.

Comment: Please always spare some time to properly write your question, so that community will ready easily to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to grab the `Parent` of the `ImageButton` and the find the `lblMsg` control.

An example of this in C# is

```
void BtnSubmit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // This gets the image button that fired
  ImageButton SubmitButton = (ImageButton)sender;
  // Get the parent container and find the lblMsg control
  Label lblMsg = (Label)SubmitButton.Parent.FindControl("lblMsg");

  // Set the value of lblMsg to what you want
  lblMsg.Text = "My updated Status";
}
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, please provide other details.